# errno -71 when installing NPM

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, npm, homestead

I'm working with Laravel Homestead, and I'm trying to install npm to use Vue.js. Unfortunately, I've got the following error.

> npm ERR! code EPROTO npm ERR! syscall symlink npm ERR! path
> ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js npm ERR! dest
> /home/vagrant/code/agenda/node_modules/.bin/parser npm ERR! errno -71
> npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink
> '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js'   ... npm ERR! A complete log
> of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2021-06-22T10_09_53_969Z-debug.log

I've got the log file, but I don't know what I have to do to solve this.

Comment: How do you obtain the error, what command are you using and where are you using it?

Comment: I was trying to install npm and I wrote npm install with git bash

Comment: I saw that I've to do 2 things: to destroy the machine with the "vagrant destroy" command and to use CLI with administrator rights. And I did it. But now I'me not able to reactivate the machine.

Comment: When I try to do it, it take a long time and I've got the next message: Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period. 
If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.
If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly working and you're able to connect to the machine.

Comment: It seems it works. But not at all! I initiate Git Bash with administrador rights and I put npm install. I've got a message who propose me to install npm running "npm install -g npm@7.18.1". I did it and I added "sudo npm install -g npm@7.18.1". Now when I add "npm run dev", system indicate the next message: sh:1 mix: not found

Comment: I resolved it. I made a reinstalation of the node.js aplication and I created a new project. Everything is Okay.